# How do I calculate total hours in a GUI-based program?

Tags: java

I am creating a simple GUI-based time card. So I already have the implementation (given by a friend) but it was just made in a non-GUI program.

```
System.out.print("Enter time-in: ");
String strTimein = input.next();
String timeInArr[] = strTimein.split(":");
double dblTimeInHr = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[0]);
double dblTimeInMin = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[1]);
double dblTotalTimeIn = dblTimeInHr + (dblTimeInMin/60);
System.out.print("Enter time-out: ");
String strtimeout = input.next();
String timeOutArr[] = strtimeout.split(":");
double dblTimeOutHr = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[0]);
double dblTimeOutMin = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[1]);
double dblTotalTimeOut = dblTimeOutHr + (dblTimeOutMin/60);
totalHrs = totalHrs + (dblTotalTimeOut - dblTotalTimeIn);
```

It works actually. But I couldn't get it to work when I apply it now on my GUI-based program. So I have two JTextField, that is where the user will input the time-in and time-out. And another JTextField, total1, that is setEditable(false) where it will display the total hours.

```
total1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String timeIn = tIn1.getText();
            String timeInArr[] = strtimein.split(":");
            double dblTimeInHr = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[0]);
            double dblTimeInMin = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[1]);
            double dblTotalTimeIn = dblTimeInHr + (dblTimeInMin/60);

            String timeOut = tOut1.getText();
            String timeOutArr[] = strtimeout.split(":");
            double dblTimeOutHr = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[0]);
            double dblTimeOutMin = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[1]);
            double dblTotalTimeOut = dblTimeOutHr + (dblTimeOutMin/60);

            totalHours = totalHours + (dblTotalTimeOut - dblTotalTimeIn);

            tal1.setText(totalHours);
     }
});
```

The error I'm getting is "cannot find symbol" which points to:

```
String timeInArr[] = strTimein.split(":");
```

and

```
String timeOutArr[] = strTimeOut.split(":");
```

I know there's something wrong with my code, but I couldn't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: In your `actionPerformed()` method you have `strtimein` and in your error you have `strTimein`. Notice the capital? Which is the correct?

Comment: Can you post the exact exception please?

Answer (score 1):

`strtimein` is not declared anywhere, you probably meant to use `timeIn`.

Comment: Oh goodness how stupid of me. yeah I guess I meant to use timeIn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared those two strings in your code..
create these two `strTimeOut` and `strTimeIn` 
Seems you actually wanted to use `timeIn` and `timeOut`

Comment: @ciara then you can upvote answer and accept any of the given answers

Answer (score 0):

Well....

```
String timeIn = tIn1.getText();
String timeInArr[] = strtimein.split(":");
```

I guess you want to split the content of the textfield `tIn1`, so you should not use `strtimein` but `timeIn`. `strtimein` is not declared anywhere and that's what your error message says.

```
String timeInArr[] = timeIn.split(":");
```

The same goes for `timeOut` / `strTimeOut` below