# Why is there a word null to the output?

Tags: java

When I click the compute button of my application, it displays the output in the JTextField. But theres always the string "null" prepended and I can't explain to myself why this happens.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
total1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String timeIn = tIn1.getText();
        String timeInArr[] = strtimein.split(":");
        double dblTimeInHr = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[0]);
        double dblTimeInMin = Double.parseDouble(timeInArr[1]);
        double dblTotalTimeIn = dblTimeInHr + (dblTimeInMin/60);

        String timeOut = tOut1.getText();
        String timeOutArr[] = strtimeout.split(":");
        double dblTimeOutHr = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[0]);
        double dblTimeOutMin = Double.parseDouble(timeOutArr[1]);
        double dblTotalTimeOut = dblTimeOutHr + (dblTimeOutMin/60);

        totalHours = totalHours + (dblTotalTimeOut - dblTotalTimeIn);

        tal1.setText(totalHours);
     }
});
```

And here is a screen of my GUI:
[image: timecard]

Why is there a null? Please help

Comment: you have something extra in your code that is returning a null and it's printing it out

Comment: can you put some code arround , i would suggest specially pur the action performed part

Comment: The code I used is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960996/how-do-i-calculate-total-hours-in-a-gui-based-program Please take a look thanks

Comment: Ciara, please take note of my edits. The provided code is still incomplete (maybe you can provide the declaration of `totalHours`). However, there is now enough information so people can help you without digging through your previous questions. Please make sure to include all the necessary bits of information and omit all the unrelevant stuff next time. Preparing a good question may take some time and is often rewarded with a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code from your last question is somewhat recent, I'd guess it's that line:

```
totalHours = totalHours + (dblTotalTimeOut - dblTotalTimeIn);
```

If `totalHours` was `null` it concats "null" with the result of `dblTotalTimeOut - dblTotalTimeIn` (which is implicitly converted to `String` due to the concatenation).

Note that the declaration of `totalHours` is not included in your code, so I have to guess it's a `String` (which does not make that much sense) because you call `tal1.setText(totalHours);`.

Comment: Oh I see now. It was declared private String totalHours; so I figured I should have typed private String totalHours = ""; and bam it worked. Thank you so much!